# How can I add the option to format to list in RichTextToolbarButton?

Tags: block-editor, formatting

I'm looking for how to add an option to RichTextToolbarButton, the goal is that when selected, the text becomes a list. I have managed to make it become a list but the entire paragraph and not just the selected text.

```
/**
 * Function to format the ordered list, it remains to be developed, but the initial idea is already there.
 * 
 * For more documentation see:
 * 
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/format-api/
 * @see https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/0638a8c52199381080abb809fd5ccd137db5bb45/packages/format-library
 * @see https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/rich-text/README.md
 * @see https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/f8491526c087d90f9f755d26270ef11cb412c788/packages/rich-text/README.md#toggleformat
 * @see https://jasonyingling.me/building-custom-gutenberg-blocks-with-the-richtext-component/
 * 
 */
import { RichTextToolbarButton } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { registerFormatType, slice, toHTMLString, create } from '@wordpress/rich-text';

const OrderedList = ({ isActive, onChange, value }) => {
    function setList(value) { 
        
        let newValue = slice(value); 
        
        newValue = toHTMLString({ value: newValue, multilineTag: 'li'});

        newValue = create({ html: newValue }); 
        
        newValue = toHTMLString({ value: newValue, multilineTag: 'ol' });

        newValue = create({ html: newValue });
        
        //Hasta aqui hemos logrado el objetivo, falta agregar el ol

        return newValue;
    }
    return (
        <RichTextToolbarButton
            icon="editor-ol"
            title="Ordered List"
            onClick={() => {
                onChange(setList(value));
            } }
            isActive={ isActive }
        />
    );
};

registerFormatType( 'text-format/ordered-list', {
    title: 'Ordered List',
    tagName: 'ol',  
    multiline:'li',
    className: null,
    edit: OrderedList
})
```

I share my code [List Format](https://gist.github.com/Gergab00/016d63b335531e536a1ebc1ac18ba2a5#file-ordered_list-js)

There are also some links to the documentation from where I am obtaining the information, I hope you can help me and from this moment thank you